# Locked out of BIOS, need to boot from USB?

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb, bios

My **Lenovo y570** was victim to a virus while browsing without any antivirus software. After a few minutes i saw a blue screen, then when trying to boot i see:

```
no bootable device found -- insert boot disk and press any key
```

So i got a USB, installed an .iso with Unebootin, then put it into the lenovo. Unfortunately you need to go into BIOS to boot from the USB.

I for the life of me have no clue what the BIOS password is or how i can get around this. Any suggestions? I read something about jumpers somewhere, i don't mind opening the computer, but will i be able to bypass BIOS? i don't mind wiping the computer, its a brick at this point anyways.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Re: Anyway to reset the CMOS on y570?
Options

‎01-01-2013 09:49 PM

To reset the CMOS on the Y570 you need to unscrew the top part of your laptop.  Usually the CMOS battery is located under the touchpad.  You need to remove the battery connector then push the power button while the AC plug & battery is disconnected to drain the charge.

From http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/IdeaPad-Y-U-V-Z-and-P-series/Anyway-to-reset-the-CMOS-on-y570/td-p/751103/page/2

If you want the easy way... open up the compartments under your laptop, then look for the label "CLRP3"  in small white text.  Beside this label are 2 small triangle metal contacts facing against each other.  You can usually find this under the black sheet on the WLAN area, but try to look on the RAM area as well.  If you found it, remove the AC plug & battery then short those two metal contacts with a forceps or something for 20secs.

After that, re-assemble the laptop then try powering on.